# FileNotFound exception for file that exists

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to copy files from specific structure to a more archival format.

```
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("INSERT INTO BACKLOGITEM_ATTACHMENT VALUES"))
            {
                string AttachementID = line.Split(',', ')')[1];
                string FileName = AttachementsDictionary[AttachementID];
                string BacklogAttachementScrumID = BacklogLookupDictionary[AttachementID];
                BacklogItem Story = BacklogItemDictionary[BacklogAttachementScrumID];
                Product Product = ProductDictionary[Story.ProductScrumId];

                string FileToCopy = "C:\\attachments\\product" + Story.ProductScrumId + "\\attachement" + AttachementID;
                string FileToSave = "C:\\ScrumWorksAttachementExport\\" + Product.ProductName + "\\" + Product.StoryPrefix + "-" + Story.StoryTitle + "\\" + FileName;

                File.Copy(FileToCopy, FileToSave);

            }
        }
```

I am getting a file not found exception:

[image]

But the file location is correct:

[image]

Why is File.Copy() failing to move a file that appears to exist?

Comment: lol. you mustve laughed while reading the answer

Comment: Where is my dunce cap?

Comment: @DavidTunnell My own dunce cap is so worn that it has its own bugs, too.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file name in the exception has an extra "e" in it: "attach**e**ment10341".  The file system does not: "attachment10341".